# terraform: aws_route_table_association error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Error: Error creating route table association: InvalidRouteTableID.NotFound: The routeTable ID 'rtb-0208e6570f55bc571' does not exist  status code: 400, request id: ecc6960b-2351-4603-add2-60e30ca77e10

But i am able to associate it without any issue manually. It is failing only with "rt_assocation_oregon" resource.

```
Full code:

#Create VPC in us-east-1
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = " test1"
}
#Create VPC in us-west-2
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
  profile = "test1"
  alias   = "west"
}
#Create VPC in us-east-1
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_master" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "master-vpc-jenkins"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_master_oregon" {
  cidr_block           = "192.168.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  provider             = aws.west
  tags = {
    Name = "worker-vpc-jenkins"
  }
}

#Create IGW in us-east-1
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_master.id

  tags = {
    Name = "master_igw"
  }
}

#Create IGW in us-west-2

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw-oregon" {
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc_master_oregon.id
  provider = aws.west

  tags = {
    Name = "worker_igw"
  }
}

#Create subnet # 1 in us-east-1
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc_master.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "master_subnet1"
  }
}

#Create subnet in us-west-2

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_oregon_1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.vpc_master_oregon.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.1.0/24"
  provider   = aws.west

  tags = {
    Name = "worker_subnet1"
  }
}

#Initiate Peering connection request from us-east1
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "useast1_uswest2" {
  peer_vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_master_oregon.id
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.vpc_master.id
  auto_accept = false
  peer_region = "us-west-2"

  tags = {
    Name = "VPC Peering between vpc_master and vpc_master_oregon"
  }
}

#Accept VPC peering request in us-west-2 from us-east-1
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "accepter_peering" {
  provider                  = aws.west
  vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.useast1_uswest2.id
  auto_accept               = true

  tags = {
    Side = "Receiver"
  }
}

#Create route table in us-east-1
resource "aws_route_table" "internet_route" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_master.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
  }
  route {
    cidr_block                = "192.168.1.0/24"
    vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.useast1_uswest2.id
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "Master-Region-RT"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_assocation_east" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.internet_route.id
}
#Create route table in us-west-2
resource "aws_route_table" "internet_route_oregon" {
  provider = aws.west
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc_master_oregon.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw-oregon.id
  }
  route {
    cidr_block                = "10.0.1.0/24"
    vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.useast1_uswest2.id
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "Worker-Region-RT"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_association_oregon" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_oregon_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.internet_route_oregon.id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `aws_subnet.subnet_oregon_1` and `aws_route_table.internet_route_oregon` are created in `us-west-2`, but you are trying to create association in `us-west-1`. It should be:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_association_oregon" {

  provider = aws.west

  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_oregon_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.internet_route_oregon.id
}
```